# Forme neutre pour les étudiants et les étudiantes à l'université

Tags: accord, genre, québec

Le français n'est pas ma langue maternelle. Je rédige des plans de cours (*syllabus*) à mon université qui se trouve au Québec. Pour respecter le principe [d'égalité des genres](http://www.unesco.org/new/fr/unesco/themes/gender-equality/), je veux utiliser une forme neutre dans mon texte. Voici une phrase typique qui n'est pas neutre:

> ... un **<del>étudiant</del>** ayant des questions à propos de l’évaluation de son examen doit ...

*Étudiant* dans ce cas n'est pas neutre, puisque il pourrait s'agir d'une étudiante.

Alors, une solution acceptable est d'utiliser un doublet:

> ... **un étudiant ou une étudiante** ayant des questions ...

Pour alléger le texte, j'aimerais voir si d'autres solutions pourraient s'appliquer:

- **<del>un apprenant</del>** (nom <del>épicène</del>)
- **un élève** (nom épicène)
- **un membre de la population étudiante inscrit dans ce cours** (nom collectif) Ok, c'est très long, mais y en a-t-il une variante plus courte?

Quelle est la meilleure forme (idéalement sans utiliser le doublet)?

J'évite les formes tronquées, p.ex. **un(e) étudiant(e)** puisque ça nuit à la lisibilité.

Comment: Je rédige la question pour indiquer que c'est une université au Québec.

Comment: Est-ce que mettre au pluriel serait une solution? Un groupe hypothétique où l'on s'attend qu'il y ait des membres de l'un et l'autre sexe est généralement désigné au neutre, qui se trouve avoir la même forme que le masculin: «les étudiants» en ce cas. Je crois qu'en France, ça passerait sans problème. Au Québec, je suis moins certain, mais je propose pareil, au cas où.

Comment: @Feelew Mettre au pluriel est la stratégie en anglais pour éviter un choix entre "his/her" (je suis de langue maternelle anglaise), mais au Québec je n'ai pas vu cette façon de faire, au moins pas dans les stratégies documentées sur Wikipedia: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langage_non_sexiste#Fran.C3.A7ais

Comment: Référence pour les dénominations utilisées dans l'enseignement au Québec: https://www.cstj.qc.ca/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/cstj_valorisationLangue_eleve_etudiant.pdf

Comment: Merci @Voléedechênesetrosiers pour ces références. Selon le conseil pour les [Statuts et règlements d'associations](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=3972), une forme au pluriel est une *rédaction au masculin*. P.ex., au lieu de "L’Assemblée générale doit élire les *candidats* qui se présentent aux différents postes." on propose d'écrire "L’Assemblée générale doit élire les *candidats* et les *candidates* qui se présentent aux différents postes." Je pense que ça serait applicable également avec le mot étudiant. Le pluriel *étudiants* est une rédaction au masculin.

Comment: ref: BDL: [étudiant](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4595), [épicène](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=%C3%A9pic%C3%A8ne&T3.x=0&T3.y=0), ex. portail [Ministère Qc](http://www.education.gouv.qc.ca/ministere-de-leducation-et-de-lenseignement-superieur/), @Fuhrmanator Je comprends. Je pense que c'est un choix, et qu'au-delà de la nature du choix comme telle c'est surtout l'uniformité et la cohérence dans l'application du choix qui sont importantes. Parfois on voit même une explication du choix dans la documentation ou dans un autre document. Merci.

Comment: Je ne savais pas qu'_apprenant_ était épicène. Ne dit-on pas _une apprenante_? D'autre part, épicène ou pas, il reste à régler le cas de l'article _un_ / _une_. Y a-t-il d'autre choix que  masculin générique vs. écriture inclusive?

Comment: @mouviciel j'ai modifé la question pour apprenant/e - en effet ce n'est pas épicène

Comment: J'ai trouvé ce guide assez complet avec des références à la fin : https://issuu.com/bernerfachhochschule/docs/bfh_leitfaden_gleichstellung_f

Comment: @Azaghal Ça dépend de la définition. "Épicène, adjectif, Dont le féminin et le masculin ont la même forme" est une définition donnée par plusieurs dictionnaires.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

En France il est naturel et habituel de parler des **étudiants**, le terme couvre les deux sexes.

*Apprenant* pourrait être utilisé dans le supérieur et serait compris mais de fait le terme n'est quasiment employé que pour le primaire et et le secondaire, pas dans le cadre administratif mais dans les contextes d'apprentissage, et aucun enseignant ne s'adresserait à, ou ne parlerait de ses élèves ou étudiants en les appelants « apprenants ».

*Élève* n'est jamais utilisé pour des étudiants dans une université, il peut l'être pour les élèves des [grandes écoles](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grande_%C3%A9cole).

*Population étudiante* est surtout utilisé dans un contexte sociologique, ce serait compris, mais ça surprend dans le contexte décrit dans la question, surtout de parler de « membre » de la population étudiante.

Si tu ne veux pas utiliser le terme « étudiants » pour parler des deux sexes tu peux opter pour : « **les personnes** inscrites à ce cours / ayant des questions à poser...  »

Comment: Et, en parlant d'égalitarianisme de genre, s'il y a dans son cours ceux qui ne s'identifient pas comme personne, mais comme une autre forme de "otherkin"? Il y serait offensif de les exclure.

Answer (score 2):

Une solution possible que j'ai rencontrée plusieurs fois, en France et plus précisément dans le monde académique des maths, de la physique, de l'ingénierie, etc. est ledit *[masculin générique](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26532333)*.

Par exemple, voici un extrait d'un fiche de poste :

> Pour faciliter la lecture du document, le **masculin générique** se réfère
>   aussi bien aux femmes qu’aux hommes.
>
> Obligation est faite au futur enseignant de participer à la vie de
>   l’établissement à savoir : réunion de département, comités
>   pédagogiques, jury, surveillance d’examen, correction de copies, etc.
>   (...)

Je ne sais pas si c'est bien acceptable par des grammairien(ne)s mais je trouve cette solution de contournement simple et utile.

Comment: Beaucoup de grammairiens défendent la masculin générique qui est enseigné depuis des lustres en France et soutenu par l'Académie française mais la question écarte d'emblée cette approche qui ne respecte pas l'égalité des genres d'après les critères de l'Unesco.

Comment: @jlliagre  Merci pour le commentaire. Le monde scientifique et technique (maths, ingénierie, physique, etc.) adoptent de telles modifications plus lentement que le monde des lettres et de la littérature. Bien des fiches de postes que j'ai vus font encore la différence entre Madame et Mademoiselle...

Comment: Il ne s'agit pas tant d'une différence liée aux spécialités enseignées qu'une différence idéologique. La défense ou l'attaque de cette évolution est assez clairement marquée politiquement.

Answer (score 2):

Dans mon université pour pallier ce problème les administrations utilisent l’écriture inclusive ci-dessous :

> Les étudiant.e.s.

Comment: Bravo pour rajouter cette solution. Je l'ai rencontrée plusieurs fois.

Comment: La question précise: "J'évite les formes tronquées, p.ex. un(e) étudiant(e) puisque ça nuit à la lisibilité." L’écriture dite inclusive n’est pas moins tronquée que la version traditionnelle avec des parenthèses.

Comment: Beaucoup de fiches de postes lors du concours de Maître des Conférences comportent cette solution de contournement avec les points. Au lieu d'étudiants , on a enseignants ; **les enseignants.e.s.**. Or, je parle selon mon expérience en France. Je ne sais pas ce qui se passe dans le monde académique francophone hors d'elle.

Comment: j'ai aussi vu sous la forme *étudiant(e)s*, mais comme le mentione @Azaghal la question spécifie que cette réponse est indésirable.

Comment: Mais cette utilisation est offensive à ceux qui s'identifient avec d'autres genres non-binaires ayant ses propres pronoms.

Answer (score 1):

The plural that works so well in English is useless in French, where plurals are also gendered.
Don't use eleve, which skews toward primary school or at most high school.  The other synonyms proposed are just awkward and don't help your quandry.
I think your only solution is re-phrasing so you're using 'les personnes' instead of 'les etudiants'.  While the gender of the noun is female, it's understood to be strongly gender-neutral.

You can also use the feminine sprinkled randomly and equally, as long as it's not reinforcing the stereotypes of all professors are male etc.  The reaction to that will make it very clear how 'neutral' the convention of including the feminine into the masculine really is..